# Nightwatch, afterEach, browser.pause is not a function

Tags: nightwatch.js

I would like to make pause each test.
I've create this function:

```
afterEach:function(browser){
   browser.pause(2000);
},
```

But when I run tests, I will get error:

> TypeError: browser.pause is not a function

Why ? In tests browser.pause is function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written on GitHub as issue and I've got a solution: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/921

RESOLVE:

use

```
afterEach(done) {
  // ...
 done(); 
}
```

instead of

```
afterEach(browser, done) {
  // ...
 done(); 
}
```

Comment: Please include the important parts of your answer here.

Answer (score 4):

The answer, provided by [beatfactor](https://github.com/beatfactor), on the [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/921), is

> When using afterEach you need to use the done callback argument always if you want to use the browser object. That is for backwards compatibility. So you need to do either:

```html
afterEach(browser, done) {
  // ...
 done(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `afterEach`, if you want access to the `browser` object then you need to add the `done` callback argument after `browser` to your function.

So your function should look like this:

```
afterEach(browser, done) {
  // ...
 done(); 
}
```

Note that you have to call `done()` to signify the completion of the test.

If you only have one argument in `afterEach` then it's the `done` argument.

```
afterEach(done) {
  // ...
 done(); 
}
```

In other words, if you write

```
afterEach(browser) {
  // ...
}
```

`browser` is actually the `done` callback. You've named it browser but that's not what it is.

Answer (score -3):

My dear friend you have to do "something" and then pause!
(i.e. assert the url and then pause!)

Does it works?

afterEach:function(browser){
  browser
    .assert.urlEquals('http://www.google.com')
    .pause(2000)
},

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I wrote "browser.assert.title('Title');", I've got "cannot read property title of undefined" . When I use "browser.pause" in beforeEach, everything works.