# close browser session after failed assertion with nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert, nightwatch.js, assertions

I implement a new testframework for automated tests in node.js with Nightwatch-Cucumber that based on Nightwatch.js. So, sometimes I use node.js Assertions to check some values. I work with the PageObject Pattern in my framework. My problem is that the browser session doen't close after a failed assertion and I don't know why and I don't know how to solve the problem.

Here is my StepDefinition:

```
const {
  client
} = require('nightwatch-cucumber');
const {
  defineSupportCode
} = require('cucumber');

const page = client.page.page();

defineSupportCode(({Given, When, Then}) => {
  When(/^test$/, () => {
    return page.test();
  });
});
```

And that's my PageObject function:

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {},
  commands: [{
    test() {
      //here the assertion failed and the browser session still exist and doen't close
      this.assert.equal(false, true);

      return this.api;
    }
  }]
};
```

So, what can I do to realize it to close the browser and the session for ths test? It happened only if the node.js assertions fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `after` or `afterEach` hook to always close the browser at the end of a test, regardless of outcome. See http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-before-each-and-after-each-hooks

```js
after : function(browser) {
  console.log('Closing down...');
  browser.end();
},
```

Comment: Your solution won't work,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309656/nightwatch-aftereach-browser-pause-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

To close your session after each test you have to add `afterEach` hook to your test file and use it like this:

```
afterEach : function(browser, done) {
  browser.end(function(){
    done();
  });
}
```